# How to make a List that contains another list, in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to make an app in flutter, I now have an app that adds a new element into a list upon pressing a FAB. Kindly let me know how can I map another ListViewBuilder to each element. I am not sure if I am being clear enough, but I am trying to be clearer. I want an app that lets you create lists inside of lists, in flutter. So for each List element, there lies a corresponding list in which the contents of the list can be added. I am a beginner, and I am struggling to figure it out. plzzz, help me out..thanks in advance...

Comment: could you share your lists and code?

Answer (score 0):

To create a list in a list you can use:

```
List<List<int>> numbers = new List<List<int>>();
```

And then you can add a new list to this by doing:

```
numbers.add([0,1,2]);
```

This adds the list [0,1,2] to the list called numbers.

From here you can access an element in this case the second element in the first list:

```
x = numbers[0][1]
```